# Send html video object (canvas) to Flask using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask, html5-video

i have been trying get user image from camera using flask but i have been receiving base64 encoded image but which is not decodable. i have been trying various codes from different platforms still unable to get the desired result

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function (stream) {
        //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.srcObject = stream;
        console.log(stream)
        video.play();
    });
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('video');
//ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {

    data = canvas.toDataURL("");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/submit", //I have doubt about this url, not sure if something specific must come before "/take_pic"
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                //alert('Your file was successfully uploaded!');
            } else {
               // alert('There was an error uploading your file!');
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('There was an error uploading your file!');
        }
    }).done(function () {
        console.log("Sent");
    });


}
```

on my flask app i have been trying various things changed js multiple time but i could not get the proper result

```
@app.route('/submit',methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    image = flask.request.data
    # print()
    # offset = image.index(',')+1
    print(image)
    # print(image)
    # print(offset)
    # input()
    # img_bytes = base64.decode(image[offset:],"utf-8")
    # input()
    # img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_bytes))
    # img  = np.array(img)
    # cv2.imshow(img)
    # cv2.waitKeys(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    # print(image)
    return ""
```

whatever i do i always is receiving

b'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAHgCAYAAAA10dzkAAAEvklEQVR4nO3BAQ0AAADCoPdPbQ43oAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD4Mwu4AAehrHaUAAAAASUVORK5CYII='

Comment: **(1)** Your canvas isn't drawing anything in your code so you wont have any pixels to `.dataURL` into anything. **(2)** Why declare as `var context` but then also try using `ctx.drawImage` (which would error), should it not be set correctly as `context.drawImage`? **(3)** Timer is too soon, so in 1 second maybe video object is still being initialized. Why not wait 5 seconds or until there is picture from camera (then a button starts the Timer function to run every second)

Comment: i am processing those image for face recognition so i need as much as image i can for faster processing and identification... and thank you for the response

Answer (score 1):

Basically my mistake was that I was **not drawing anything to canvas** so that was causing error for receiving the image.

This is the working version below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    </body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function     (stream) {
                 //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.srcObject = stream;
                console.log(stream)
                video.play();
            });
    }

    setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
    
    function myTimer() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        ctx.drawImage(video,0,0)
        ctx.translate(video,0)
        document.getElementById("canvas").style = "display:none;"
        //ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0)
        data = canvas.toDataURL("image/JPEG");

        console.log(data)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/submit",
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    //alert('Your file was successfully uploaded!');
                } else {
                   // alert('There was an error uploading your file!');
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('There was an error uploading your file!');
            }
        }).done(function () {
            console.log("Sent");
        });


    }    

</script>

</html>
```